# How to add python to XAMPP

Tags: python, xampp, mod-wsgi

I've used all the time XAMPP to test my PHP applications and I got used to it. Now, I would like to start my adventure with Python. I've heard that good solution is using mod_wsgi, but it doesn't work on my PC. I followed this tutorial: [Setting Python Path in Windows XAMPP using WSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891996/setting-python-path-in-windows-xampp-using-wsgi/4306903#4306903)

I got these errors:

```
[Mon Aug 08 12:27:28 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.
[Mon Aug 08 12:27:28 2011] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.2.
[Mon Aug 08 12:27:30 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Aug 08 12:27:30 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Aug 08 12:27:30 2011] [notice] Child 4884: Child process is running
[Mon Aug 08 12:27:30 2011] [notice] Child 4884: Acquired the start mutex.
[Mon Aug 08 12:27:30 2011] [notice] Child 4884: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Aug 08 12:27:30 2011] [notice] Child 4884: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Mon Aug 08 12:27:30 2011] [notice] Child 4884: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Mon Aug 08 12:27:30 2011] [notice] Child 4884: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Mon Aug 08 12:27:30 2011] [notice] Child 4884: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

I don't have installed mod_python. When I enter 'localost/wsgi/test.wsgi' i get 'Error 403' in my browser.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Hopefully you're really typing 'localhost/wsgi/test.wsgi' into your browser.  If the URL you used in your test has 'localost' (missing 'h'), that would cause an error (although I wouldn't expect a 403).  BTW, those log messages aren't errors.

Comment: I type 'localhost' I did mistake here.

Comment: Error 403
localhost
2011-08-08 21:55:55
Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.2 mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Comment: Post the snippets of your Apache configuration where you mapped the WSGI application. The 403 error suggests you haven't set it up right in Apache configuration or using the wrong URL. We can't tell unless you supply those bits of the Apache configuration.

Comment: httpd.conf:
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
Include "conf/other/wsgi.conf"

conf/other/wsgi.conf:
<Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/wsgi/scripts">
  Options ExecCGI Indexes
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi  
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
Alias /wsgi/ "D:/xampp/htdocs/wsgi/scripts/"
<IfModule wsgi_module>
  WSGIScriptAlias /test "D:/xampp/htdocs/wsgi/scripts/test.wsgi"
</IfModule>

Comment: @ManuszPaleo:  Thanks for posting the configuration; however, it would be much easier to read that if you edited it into the question marked as code.